# Can't change return address of the function x64

Tags: c, gdb, stack, buffer-overflow

I am trying to change the return address of some function in C for skipping one instruction. I am doing this on virtual machine with Ubuntu Server (because on Mac gcc doesn't let me turn off stack protection).

I am compiling my code with gcc:

> gcc –g –fno-stack-protector –z execstack –o bufover bufover.c

This is the code:

```
void foo(int a, int b, int c) {
   char buff[256];
   long *ret, *ret2;

   ret = buff + 256 + 8;
   (*ret) += 5; 
}

int main() {
  char x;
  x = '0';
  foo(1,2,3);
  x = '1';
  printf("%c\n",x);
}
```

To the address of *buff* I added 256 (size of buff) and 8 (size of %RBP). Before this on the stack should be return address. 
Next I added 5 bytes to the address that, because I checked using gdb that next instruction is in 5 bytes.

But it doesn't work...
I am analyzing the variables (addresses) step by step using gdb but I am not seeing any mistake.
Any idea?

Edit: Assembly code:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 10, 14
    .globl  _foo                    ## -- Begin function foo
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_foo:                                   ## @foo
Lfunc_begin0:
    .file   1 "me.c"
    .loc    1 3 0                   ## me.c:3:0
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $160, %rsp
    leaq    -272(%rbp), %rax
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    %edx, -12(%rbp)
Ltmp0:
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: foo:buff <- [%rax+0]
    .loc    1 7 19 prologue_end     ## me.c:7:19
    addq    $256, %rax              ## imm = 0x100
Ltmp1:
    .loc    1 7 25 is_stmt 0        ## me.c:7:25
    addq    $8, %rax
    .loc    1 7 12                  ## me.c:7:12
    movq    %rax, -280(%rbp)
    .loc    1 8 10 is_stmt 1        ## me.c:8:10
    movq    -280(%rbp), %rax
    .loc    1 8 15 is_stmt 0        ## me.c:8:15
    movq    (%rax), %rcx
    addq    $5, %rcx
    movq    %rcx, (%rax)
    .loc    1 9 5 is_stmt 1         ## me.c:9:5
    addq    $160, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
Ltmp2:
Lfunc_end0:
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ## -- End function
    .globl  _main                   ## -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
Lfunc_begin1:
    .loc    1 11 0                  ## me.c:11:0
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $1, %edi
    movl    $2, %esi
    movl    $3, %edx
Ltmp3:
    .loc    1 13 9 prologue_end     ## me.c:13:9
    movb    $48, -1(%rbp)
    .loc    1 14 7                  ## me.c:14:7
    callq   _foo
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    .loc    1 15 9                  ## me.c:15:9
    movb    $49, -1(%rbp)
    .loc    1 16 21                 ## me.c:16:21
    movsbl  -1(%rbp), %esi
    .loc    1 16 7 is_stmt 0        ## me.c:16:7
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   _printf
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    .loc    1 17 5 is_stmt 1        ## me.c:17:5
    movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)          ## 4-byte Spill
    movl    %edx, %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
Ltmp4:
Lfunc_end1:
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ## -- End function
    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:                                 ## @.str
    .asciz  "%c\n"

    .section    __DWARF,__debug_str,regular,debug
```

Comment: This isn't possible to do safely in standard C. You must use assembler or non-standard extensions.

Comment: http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs161/fa08/papers/stack_smashing.pdf page no 5, this is my base. It says that it possible

Comment: Compile with `-S` and paste the generated assembly into the question.

Comment: @demoo _"It says that it possible"_: that means basically: it was possible with the particular compiler on the particular platform used by the author at the time the document has been written.

Comment: @Jabberwocky probably you are right, but I don't want to give up. Also I changed /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space from 2 to 0. Result still the same...

Comment: The document is for x86 assembly, but you're using x64 assembly. Compile your code with the `-m32` switch `gcc –g –fno-stack-protector -m32 –z execstack –o bufover bufover.c`

Answer (score 0):

You should use GCC [return-address related](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html#Return-Address) builtins like `__builtin_frame_address` or `__builtin_return_address`, and you should carefully study the [x86-64 ABI specification](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI) to understand *in details* the relevant [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

Try also to understand them by writing some C code in `foo.c`, and compiling it with `gcc -O -fverbose-asm -S foo.c` then looking into the generated `foo.s`

At last, the stack segment is usually not executable (this could matter for some [trampoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)) techniques). Read about the [NX bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit). On Linux, learn to use [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html), [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html), [backtrace(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html).

There is no guarantee that GCC even uses any [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). It could optimize to avoid using it ([tail-call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimization *could* happen sometimes), and your code might not even need additional call frames. So of course you cannot achieve your goal in standard C, or without additional hypothesis on your particular GCC compiler (and GCC 8 and GCC 9 could optimize differently).

Of course, changing the return address is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: The code is not trying to execute the stack, only modify its contents by adding to the return address that is presumably there.